# Textarea line breaks in IE8 with long string of text

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, textarea

Take a long continuous string of text like so:

```
Question?Thisisanissuewithusingquestionmarks
```

In all versions of IE, the line breaks unexpectedly after the question mark. In  IE9+ this is countered by using `white-space: pre;`, but IE8 seems to ignore it (even though it's supported). The only way I've been able to get this to wrap as normal (i.e. not line break at the question mark) is by using a mono-spaced font, but this also extends the length of the textarea. Any ideas?

**To summarize:** I want a HTML/CSS solution to having the line not break on to a new line after the ? mark in IE8.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8m5yea9y/

Example of how it's working fine in IE9+ using `white-space: pre;`

[image]

Comment: how do you want in the straight line or it should be wrap

Comment: I want it to wrap in IE8 like it does in IE9+ (it's wraps after applying `white-space: pre`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `word-break: break-all;` to your css for the `textarea` should cause the line to break as desired. You may also need to add `word-wrap: break-word;`.

**Added Screenshot:** Tested and works in IE8 on windows XP.
[image]

Comment: Interesting! In my local version in the gif above this works, but not in our production environment, so there may be something else affecting it. If no other answer can offer anything else I'll mark as correct.

Comment: @PaulRedmond - You may also need `word-wrap: break-word;`.  Also, make sure the textarea element [hasLayout‌](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530764%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)​. Setting the display as `block` or `inline-block` should do it.

Comment: Nice idea with the hasLayout. I tried as you suggested all above but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: @PaulRedmond - I posted a screenshot of this working on windows XP IE8. Are you testing by emulation or with the actual browser? I have noticed some inconsistencies with using older IE modes in newer browsers compared to the using the real thing.

Comment: I'm going to mark as correct, your example works perfectly. I'm still encountering an issue but it must be something else affecting the layout. Thanks!